# C++ Calculator class give me the lowest possible int spread over multiple cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm starting to learn C++, but I'm a bit stuck on this exercise. I need to make a working calculator in c++ over multiple CPP files and a header file, but every time I run this code I get -9.25596e+61 back instead of 15.

Sincerely
Tom

pch.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"


Calculator::Calculator(double X, double Y) {

    GetalSet(a, b);
}
void Calculator::GetalSet(double X, double Y)
{
    a = X;
    b = Y;
}
void Calculator::add() { a + b == result; }
void Calculator::print() { cout << result << endl;  }
```

pch.h:

```
using namespace std;


class Calculator
{   
private:
    double a;
    double b;
    double result;
public:

    int GetA() { return a; }
    int GetB() { return b; }

    Calculator(double X, double Y);
    void GetalSet(double X, double Y);
    void add();
    void print();

};
```

ConsoleApplicaton.cpp:

```
void main()
{
    Calculator Calc(10, 10);
    Calc.add();
    Calc.print();

}
```

Comment: `a + b == result;` is merely a NOP. Did you mean to write `result = a + b;`?

Comment: Note: If you have pre-compiled headers turned on, naming your main header pch.h could get ugly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Mistakes in the code aside, but why do you expect to add `10`, and `10`, and expect to get the result of `15`?

Comment: Sorry I previously tried to add 10 and 5, and I forgot I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `a + b == result` to:

```
result = a+b;
```

also initialize a and b in the constructor.

Comment: This, alone, won't fix the issue the OP is facing, due to the fact, that `a`, and `b` are uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you this works. I thought GetalSet() would do the job because I read it somewhere, but why does it need to be result = a+b and it cannot be  a + b = result?  I know == is wrong I just used it to try something else.

Comment: That syntax stuff depends on the compiler you use and is based on standards for c++, if you want to learn more check out the cpp documentation 11 14 17 or get some book on compiler design